# cygwin gcc linker cannot find -lpython2.7

Tags: python, gcc, dll, cygwin, shared

I've already compiled several .c programs into their corresponding .o files using gcc in cygwin as shown below:

```
gcc -fPIC -c test5*.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

Now, I am trying to link them into a dll library that can be used by python. This is where the problem starts, first, I tried the following command:

```
gcc -shared test5*.o -o test5.dll -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7
```

Then, it complains about not finding a lot of python function calls such as below:

```
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x42e0): undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTuple'
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x450e): undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTuple'
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x4924): undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x4942): undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x4963): undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
test5_wrap.o:test5_wrap.c:(.text+0x4972): undefined reference to `PyString_ConcatAndDel'
```

So, according to everybody, this is due to the need for specifying -lpython2.7, so I add it to the gcc command as below:

```
gcc -shared test5*.o -o test5.dll -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

but now, it complains of cannot find -lpython2.7:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to try and understand what you are doing, not blindly follow random advice. PyArg_ParseTuple is undefined, so you need to link with a library that defines it. That is done with `-l`. `-lfoo` looks for a file called libfoo.a or libfoo.so (maybe it also finds libfoo.lib or something on windows, I don't know). You wrote `-lpython2.7`, do you have a file called libpython2.7.so or libpython2.7.a somewhere?

Comment: @MarcGlisse, yeah, I agree, I am on windows and a lot of these instructions are for linux really. I am going to verify a bit more to post a definitive response. But I just wish people post things and say it clearly what platform did they actually make it work...